# How to define Data Contracts in WCF?

Tags: c#, wcf, datacontract

I am newbie to WCF. Hence, this question. I am in the process of converting an asmx web service to WCF service.

I am having trouble defining data contracts.

I have two operations on my service contract, one returns an array of `Customer`, where `Customer` is my custom type with some fields.

Here, my question is which needs to declared as data contract.

Is it the `Customer` class or `Customers` class which contains an array of `Customer` or is it both?

Please do suggest

Comment: I would define `Customer` class, and then return a collection of that class or a single instance, depending on what the operation returns.

Comment: The operation contract returns array of customers which mean Customer and Customers both of them goes outside of the service.So, i do think both of them should be defined as Data Contracts..Is that what are you trying to say ? if i am not wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should read this MSDN article on DataContracts: [Using Data Contracts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733127%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

In short:

You should define the `DataContract` attribute on every class you use in your service that goes across the line, so you would need the attribute on both `Customer` and `Customers`.

Comment: @Patrick..Thanks for simple and clear explantion. I too thought the same but just wanted to confirm..:)

Answer (score 1):

Please check this sample code. In following class file i had create data contract for my wcf service. use namespace System.Runtime.Serialization for serialize the data.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

namespace BusinessLogic
{
     [DataContract]
     [Serializable]
     public class POSTheaterListArgs
    {
    public POSTheaterListArgs()
    {
        TheaterDates = new List<string>();
    }
    [DataMember]
    public List<string> TheaterDates { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int TheaterId { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int NumofScreen { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int? CompanyId { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int ChainId { get; set; }
    [DataMember]


    private int _Number;
    public int Number { get { return _Number; } set { _Number = value; } }

    private bool _status;
    public bool status { get { return _status; } set { _status = value; } }

}
```

For array data

```
    public POSTheaterListArgs()
    {
        TheaterDates = new List<string>();
    }
    [DataMember]
    public List<string> TheaterDates { get; set; }
```

will return you list array structure.

This may help you....

Comment: Do we need to explicitly mention [Serializable] ? Is declaring class as a DataContract good enough?

Comment: Yes, [Serializable] is ignored if [DataContract] is present. This may be useful to e.g. create a type that will have one serialization projection for WCF, and another projection for .NET Remoting (if it is used alongside WCF for legacy reasons).

With [Serializable], all fields become part of the data contract (unless they are marked with [NonSerialized]). With [DataContract], only members marked with [DataMember] are included. Note that if a type has both [DataContract] and [Serializable] attributes on it, it will use the [DataContract] mapping